# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que cambie el color círculo en Python de acuerdo a la entrada boleana de Arduino?

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino

Necesito hacer un sistema que muestre el estado de unos sensores infrarrojos en Python en una ventana de Tkinter por medio de unos indicadores para los cuales voy a utilizar circulos rojos y verdes.
Ya Puedo leer por el puerto serial la información boleana que Arduino manda, solo necesito mostrarlo en Tkinter. pero no sé como relacionar esta información para hacer el cambio de color de un círculo.

```py
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
def Salir_programa():
    ventana.destroy()

def ventana():
    ventana =tk.Tk()
    ventana.geometry("1600x600+0+50")
    ventana.title('Requerimiento de circuitos')
    img_path = "1raparte.png"
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(img_path).resize((1175,374), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    #imagen=PhotoImage(file="1raparte.png")
    #fondo=Label(ventana,image=imagen).place(x=0, y=0)

    canvas = tk.Canvas(ventana, height=500, width=1400)
    #canvas.create_image(700, 270, image=img)
    #canvas.create_image(Canvas,700, 270, Image=img)
    indicador1=canvas.create_oval(250, 105, 310, 165, width=2, fill='lawngreen')
    indicador2=canvas.create_oval(250, 195, 310, 255, width=2, fill='red')
    indicador3=canvas.create_oval(250, 290, 310, 350, width=2, fill='lawngreen')
    indicador4=canvas.create_oval(250, 385, 310, 445, width=2, fill='lawngreen')
    indicador5=canvas.create_oval(500, 105, 560, 165, width=2, fill='red')
    indicador6=canvas.create_oval(500, 195, 560, 255, width=2, fill='lawngreen')
    indicador7=canvas.create_oval(500, 290, 560, 350, width=2, fill='lawngreen')
    indicador8=canvas.create_oval(500, 385, 560, 445, width=2, fill='lawngreen')
    indicador9=canvas.create_oval(730, 105, 790, 165, width=2, fill='lawngreen')
    indicador10=canvas.create_oval(730, 195, 790, 255, width=2, fill='lawngreen')
    indicador11=canvas.create_oval(730, 290, 790, 350, width=2, fill='red')
    indicador12=canvas.create_oval(730, 380, 790, 440, width=2, fill='lawngreen')
    indicador13=canvas.create_oval(985, 105, 1045, 165, width=2, fill='lawngreen')
    indicador14=canvas.create_oval(985, 195, 1045, 255, width=2, fill='lawngreen')
    indicador15=canvas.create_oval(985, 290, 1045, 350, width=2, fill='lawngreen')
    indicador16=canvas.create_oval(985, 380, 1045, 440, width=2, fill='lawngreen')
    indicador17=canvas.create_oval(1200, 105, 1260, 165, width=2, fill='lawngreen')
    indicador18=canvas.create_oval(1200, 195, 1260, 255, width=2, fill='lawngreen')
    indicador19=canvas.create_oval(1200, 285, 1260, 345, width=2, fill='red')
    indicador20=canvas.create_oval(1200, 380, 1260, 440, width=2, fill='lawngreen')

    canvas.pack()

    etiquetaindicador_1=Label(ventana, text="Directo(Single)\n TMF_AP117_2", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",11)).place(x=100,y=110)
    etiquetaindicador_2=Label(ventana, text="Directo(Single)\n TMF_RS328_1/ RS328_4", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",11)).place(x=45,y=205)
    etiquetaindicador_3=Label(ventana, text="Directo(Single)\n TMF_YA107_1/ YA107_2", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",11)).place(x=45,y=300)
    etiquetaindicador_4=Label(ventana, text="Directo(Single)\n TMF_SA7_1/ SA7_2", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",11)).place(x=60,y=400)
    etiquetaindicador_5=Label(ventana, text="Directo(Single)\n TMF_AS147_2", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",11)).place(x=350,y=110)
    etiquetaindicador_6=Label(ventana, text="Directo(Single)\n TMF_SA8_1/ SA8_2", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",11)).place(x=312,y=205)
    etiquetaindicador_7=Label(ventana, text="Directo(Single)\nTMF_YC1_1TMF\n_AS68_1", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",11)).place(x=335,y=300)
    etiquetaindicador_8=Label(ventana, text="Directo(Single)\n TMF_YC3_1", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",11)).place(x=350,y=400)
    etiquetaindicador_9=Label(ventana, text="Directo(Single)\n TMF_BZ1_2/ BZ1_3", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",11)).place(x=565,y=110)
    etiquetaindicador_10=Label(ventana, text="Directo(Single)\n TMF_YG34_1", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",11)).place(x=575,y=205)
    etiquetaindicador_11=Label(ventana, text="Directo(Single)\n TMF_DK13_1", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",11)).place(x=575,y=300)
    etiquetaindicador_12=Label(ventana, text="Directo(Single)\n TMF_PH990_1/\nPH990_2", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",11)).place(x=575,y=400)
    etiquetaindicador_13=Label(ventana, text="Directo(Single)\n TMF_EO111_1", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",11)).place(x=830,y=110)
    etiquetaindicador_14=Label(ventana, text="Directo(Single)\n TMF_FK2_1/ FK2_2", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",11)).place(x=815,y=205)
    etiquetaindicador_15=Label(ventana, text="Directo(Single)\n TMF_FK1_1/ FK1_2", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",11)).place(x=815,y=300)
    etiquetaindicador_16=Label(ventana, text="Directo(Single)\n TMF_HD1_1/ HD1_2", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",11)).place(x=815,y=400)
    etiquetaindicador_17=Label(ventana, text="Directo(Single)\n TMF_FK116_1/\nFK116_2", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",11)).place(x=1055,y=110)
    etiquetaindicador_18=Label(ventana, text="Directo(Single)\n TMF_HF172_2", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",11)).place(x=1055,y=205)
    etiquetaindicador_19=Label(ventana, text="Directo(Single)\n TMF_SA883_1/\nSA883_2", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",11)).place(x=1055,y=300)
    etiquetaindicador_20=Label(ventana, text="Directo(Single)\n TMF_SA881_1/\nSA881_4", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",11)).place(x=1055,y=400)


    etiqueta_1=Label(ventana, text="MESA 1",bg="gray70", fg="gray10", font=("Verdana",24)).place(x=600,y=20)
    #etiqueta_2=Label(ventana, text="NUMERO DE CIRCUITOS",bg="gray70", fg="blue2", font=("Verdana",10)).place(x=900,y=500)
    #etiqueta_3=Label(ventana, text="2", fg="blue2", font=("Verdana",10)).place(x=1070,y=500)
    salir=Button(ventana,text="Salir de la ventana ",command=ventana.destroy,relief=GROOVE,bg="red4", fg="azure").place(x=20,y=540)
    Guardar=Button(ventana,text="Guardar ",#command=ventana.destroy,
                                           relief=GROOVE,bg="red4", fg="azure",font=("Verdana",10)).place(x=1000,y=540)

#readingt = StringVar()
#sensor = Label(ventana, textvariable = readingt)
#sensor.place(x= 100, y = 100);


pfront=tk.Tk()
pfront.title("Sistema de requerimiento de ciruitos")
pfront.geometry("1600x600+0+50")
pfront.configure(background='gainsboro')

e1=tk.Label(pfront,text="SISTEMA DE REQUERIMIENTO DE CIRCUITOS",fg="dodger blue",bg='gainsboro',font=("Verdana",16))
e1.pack(padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5)
boton=tk.Button(pfront,text="Mesas de trabajo",fg="blue",font=("Verdana",10),command=ventana).place(x=1000,y=540)
botonsalir=tk.Button(pfront,text="Salir",fg="blue",font=("Verdana",10),command=pfront.destroy).place(x=100,y=540)
#boton.pack(padx=10,pady=10,ipadx=10,ipady=10)

var=tk.StringVar(pfront)
var.set('Dgo')
opciones=['Dgo','NDD']
opcion=tk.OptionMenu(pfront,var,*opciones)
opcion.config(width=20)
opcion.pack(side='left',padx=30,pady=30)
el=tk.Label(pfront,text="Planta:", bg='gainsboro', fg="dodger blue",font=("Verdana",12)).place(x=90,y=260)
#el.pack(padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tk.X)
pfront.mainloop()
```

Solo quiero que si Arduino me envía por el puerto serial un 1 o un 0 el color de los indicadores cambie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las propiedades de un widget en tkinter se pueden modificar con el metodo `configure`. Así, necesitas un lazo que lea el valor recibido por el modulo Arduino via puerto serial y dependiendo del valor que recibas, puedes por ejemplo cambiar el color del indicador 1 a rojo con:

```
etiquetaindicador_1.configure(fill='red')
```

Espero te sirva...

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. Esa funcion si me ha servido, pero lo que pasa es que solo cuando corro el programa me aparece el color del circulo segun lo que manda Arduino pero solo la primera vez, y cuando este cambia ya no hace nungun cambio.